# + operator in a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am reading John Resig's *Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja*, and I'm having some trouble understanding how the ternary operator works in this recursive function:

```
var  ninja = {
  chirp: function signal(n) {
    return n > 1 ? signal(n - 1) + '-chirp' : 'chirp';
  }
};
```

How is the `+` operator working here? I understand it's concatenating the returned strings, but how is `signal(n - 1)` not interfering with it? At first glance it would appear it's appending the string to the function call.

Comment: `signal(n-1)` must be evaluated before its value can be concatenated with `'-chrip'`.  Is that what yu're asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator appends `-chirp` to the *result* of the function call. `signal` is a recursive function - a function that calls itself.

Answer (score 2):

With some parenthesis added, it might become clearer to read:

```
return (n > 1) ? (signal(n - 1) + '-chirp') : ('chirp');
```

or as a plain `if` clause:

```
if( n > 1 ) {
  return signal(n - 1) + '-chirp';
} else {
  return 'chirp';
}
```

So actually the string `-chirp` is concatenated with the result of the recursive call to `signal()`.